# Count of ALL linked objects in django M2M object

Tags: python, django, django-models

A model is linked to several others using `ManyToMany` in the following manner:

```
class Tag(model.models):
    attributes...

class A(model.models):
    f = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class B(model.models):
    f = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class C(model.models):
    f = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

And the objective is to get a count of ALL linked objects to Tag.
So something like `count(A) + count(B) + count(C)`

Is there a better way to do it than this:

```
count = 0
count += tag.a_set.count()
count += tag.b_set.count()
count += tag.c_set.count()
```

Also, what are the options for doing this programmatically when the linked models are unknown? I.e. We do not know the model name, so doing `model_set` is not possible.

A possible way:

```py
# get count from all fields with '_set' at the end
linked_models = [
    model_set 
    for model_set in dir(Tag) 
        if model_set.endswith('_set')
]
count = sum([
        getattr(tag, model).count 
        for model in linked_models
    ])
```

Concerns:

- performance on servers: this might take too much time to generate for each tag
- there is a better way to do this: something hidden away in `_meta` perhaps that gets all linked objects together? I did not find anything (I'm sloppy!)